# Read data into a vector/scan with some limits [R]

Tags: r

I have a txt file with this reputative structure:

```
“
fileName1.doc  Author=Name
fileName2.doc  Author=Name
fileName2.doc  Author=Name
“
```

How can I save only the filenames (first 9 characters) without the extension and the authors using scan?

I used:

```
Fnames <- scan("E:/myFiles.txt",character())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To grab only the first 9 characters, scan by line with `sep="\n"` and use `substr(..., 1, 9)`.

```
substr(scan("E:/myFiles.txt", what="", sep="\n"), 1, 9)
```

You could even use `read.table()` (which uses `scan()` in the background) with `sep="."` and grab the first column. This way you wouldn't need to worry if there were file names longer than 9 characters.  It would return them all.

```
read.table("E:/myFiles.txt", sep=".", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[[1]]
```

As example of this using the `text` argument of `read.table()` follows:

```
read.table(text = x, sep = ".", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[[1]]
# [1] "fileName1" "fileName2" "fileName2"
```

Data:

```
x <- "fileName1.doc  Author=Name
fileName2.doc  Author=Name
fileName2.doc  Author=Name"
```

Comment: adding that if you have data on the order of gigabytes to process like this, `MapReduce`-family tools are far better suited

Comment: even `fread` will require dropping the whole object in to RAM before doing `substr`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with the `readr` package, which runs 10X faster than base R. Reading the file as a fixed with file allows us to only read the first 9 characters of each line, and takes advantage of `readr::read_fwf()` performance characteristics.

```
library(readr)
rawData <- "fileName1.doc  Author=Name
fileName2.doc  Author=Name
fileName2.doc  Author=Name
"
data <- read_fwf(rawData,fwf_widths(9,col_names="fileName"))
```